# VuetifyJS vertical button text

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to have text below the icon in a v-btn and can't seem to find how to do this.  How is this possible?

[image: Icon above the text]

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this look with Vuetify, you just need to overwrite the **flex direction** in the *v-btn__content* class. Don't forget to give a unique class (for me *flexcol*) to your button so the style change won't affect other Vuetify buttons.

```
<template>
<v-btn class="flexcol" icon height="100" width="100">
        <v-icon> mdi-tools </v-icon>
        <span> Tools </span>
</v-btn>
</template>


<style>
.flexcol .v-btn__content {
  flex-direction: column;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need vuetify to do that.

You can just use css and flexbox.

Say you have:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
 <div>Text Above</div>
 <div>Text Below</div>
</div>
```

You want the "Text Below" to stand below the "Text Above".You can do it like this:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

However [click here](https://codepen.io/Roland1993/pen/PavZNV?editors=1100) to see your solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-column align-center">
    <v-btn icon height="30">
      <v-icon>mdi-history</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <p class="mb-0">abc</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a clickable vertical button.  It looks like a div, with a button that has text under it.